# ImportError: No module named sysconfig, when running Python from Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, unix, anaconda

I'm trying to run the python2.7.11 version installed in the root environment in Anaconda 2.4.1. 
I should note that I do not have admin on the server (uni server) which might screwed up the installation. 
As I run *`python test_script.py`* (no matter which script), I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "Anaconda/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 230, in getuserbase
    from sysconfig import get_config_var
ImportError: No module named sysconfig
```

I should note that when I run the line `which python` I get the correct Anaconda python path, and when I run the line `python --version` I get `Python 2.7.11 :: Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)`

Comment: can you run `import sysconfig` when starting the repl?

Comment: I can only run from a sh file, as otherwise the anaconda python is not recognized, so I'm not sure how to check.

Comment: How do you install python? Do you compile from the source file?

Comment: I installed anaconda and am trying to use the default python 2.7 installation that comes with it.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem:  Script returns import error traceback, no module named sysconfig using: Python 2.7.11, Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit).  No admin permissions for local install.

### Solution:

Regarding permissions you can use virtualenv to install the packages that you need this will allow you to use your scripts without a systemwide installation. 
Regarding the import error you could hard code in your script sys.path so the interpreter finds the module that you need.

> import sys
>
> sys.path = ['','',...]
>
> sys.path.append("/path/to/module")

Here is [information](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) regarding virtualenv.